# Declaring a member object without calling its default constructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I have two classes: `Generator` and `Motor`.
Here is a stripped down version of `Generator`:

```
class Generator {
private:
    Motor motor;    // this will be initialized later
                    // However, this line causes the constructor to run.
public: 
    Generator(string);
}

Generator::Generator(string filename) {
    motor = Motor(filename);     // initialisation here
                                 
}
```

and here is the Motor class definition:

```
class Motor {
public:
    Motor();
    Motor(string filename);
}

Motor::Motor() {
    cout << "invalid empty constructor called" << endl;
}
Motor::Motor(string filename) {
    cout << "valid constructor called" << endl;
}
```

And here is my `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Generator generator = Generator(argv[1]);
    ....
    ....
}
```

The output is

> invalid empty constructor called
>
> valid constructor called

How can I define class `Generator` to have an instance of `Motor` without calling the empty constructor of `Motor`, until later on?

I had to include the empty constructor because `g++` refuses to compile without it.

Comment: Re: 'motor = Motor(filename); // initialisation here` -- the comment is wrong. That line is an **assignment**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an [intialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) construction in your `Generator` constructor:

```
Generator::Generator(string filename) : motor(filename) // initialization here
{
    // nothing needs to do be done here
}
```

What your original code is actually doing is:

```
Generator::Generator(string filename) /* : motor() */ // implicit empty initialization here
{
    motor = Motor(filename) // create a temp instance of Motor
    //    ^------------------- copy it into motor using the default operator=()
                            // destruct the temp instance of Motor
}
```